# How can I calculate the centre between two centre of rectangles in python 3?

Tags: python-3.x

I have two rectangles and I want to measure the distance between them. I have centre coordinates for both rectangle.

```
R1 = (908,1018) ## (x,y,width,height)=(595,11,627,2015)
R2 = (891,1019) ## (x,y,width,height)= (670,871,442,297)
```

I know, we can calculate it with help of Pythagoras Theory. But how can I do it with python in a simple way.

Comment: `sqrt((R1[0]-R2[0])**2 + (R1[1]-R2[1])**2 )` for the distance. Then calculate the unitary vector from R1 to R2 and scalate it by half of the distance.

Answer (score 1):

Like you said, Pythagoras works fine here. Try something like this

```
x1, y1 = R1
x2, y2 = R2

dx = x2 - x1
dy = y2 - y1
d = math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)

print(d)
```